# What did I do wrong? (PHP prepare statement)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, prepared-statement

First time I'm using a prepare function, and I got it to partially work. Basically, I'm copying user passwords from one database to another (part of a WordPress plugin I'm making to transfer users). The code runs and does exactly what I want, but only for the first user it finds in the wp_users table. I need it to continue running for all the users in that table so they all get their passwords transfered. This is the code I wrote below:

**For getting the user password from the original database** (Basically, this finds the passwords for all the users and puts them in an array. I'm posting this code just for context. This code works perfectly fine):

```
$i = 0;
//set $user_count-1 because $i needs to start at 0 to represent the indexes and it also prevents the statement from being looped an extra time.
while($i <= $user_count-1) {
if($result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM wp_users")) {
    if($count = $result->num_rows) {
        //echo $count . ' users found.';

        while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $user_password[] = $row->user_pass;
        }
    }  
$i++; 
}
```

**To retrieve the index values** (This is the code I'm using to actually retrieve those index values and put them in the sql query. Like I said, it works fine for the first user, but not the rest of the users):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `wp_plugin_development`.`wp_users` SET `user_pass` = ? WHERE `wp_users`.`user_login` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $user_password[$i], $user_login[$i]);
$stmt->execute();
```

I'm thinking maybe the syntax is wrong? I don't know. I hope I made my question clear enough. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is `'ss'` in `bind_param()` ? You have two `?`. but your param in bind are three.

Comment: Replace `$stmt->execute();` with `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$conn->error, E_USER_WARNING);}`

Comment: @stack I'm using two variables, so I put in two type specifications respectively (both of them are strings). If I change it to just `s` it gives me an error saying "Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables." So I assume I'm doing it right by putting in `ss`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I put in that code. It gave no errors. Everything worked the same as before.

Comment: Just to clarify, I think the main problem is that it's not reading all of the values available. It's just reading the first value.

Comment: where are you setting `$user_login` for `$user_login[$i]`?

Comment: yeah.. what are those `[$i]` doing in there?

Comment: Did you put your update query inside the while loop?

Comment: just thinking, why don't you use the `user_login` for the key in `$user_password[] = $row->user_pass;`, ie. `$user_password[$row->user_login] = $row->user_pass;`. Then when you do your insert, it guarantees that the values are linked.

Comment: to make this a little simpler, define your variables before you prepare them.  `$user_password[$i]` is very odd.   As is stated by the others, get the variable through your loop and then just update using `$user_password`.

Comment: my guess is; you're relying on your `$i` variables from your select and trying to apply it to your update; why? I don't know. If anything, that should either be set inside that loop, or use standard prepared statements syntax. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: then you have `wp_plugin_development.wp_users` and `wp_users.user_login` which is quite bizarre frankly. That translates to "update table.column_x SET ... column_x.column_y" which is probably why and/or another reason why it's failing. Please go over the manual for update https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: am assuming that `wp_plugin_development` is the database name?

Comment: *It is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed.* - which is something I found on MySQL.com/Stack

Comment: so just eliminate `wp_users.` from the `WHERE` clause. keep me posted

Comment: @Fred-ii- I took out the `wp_user` from the `WHERE` clause and it actually works the same as before. I'll keep it out since it's the proper syntax. For clarity, `wp_plugin_development` is the database, `wp_users` is a table. And `user_pass` and `user_login` are columns.

Comment: @Fred-ii- As for the $i variable: $i is auto-incrementing after every loop, starting from zero. I use it for a couple things, but here it's basically looping through the indexes based on how many users are in the database. Once it can't find any more users, it stops looping. Using it to insert user names, emails, etc. works perfectly with WordPress's  wp_insert_user function. But if I use that function to insert a password, it "rehashes" the hashed password. So this is why I'm trying to use a query update as a more direct approach.

Answer (score 1):

**I figured it out!**

Originally, I put the code to prepare the statement and the code to execute it together. `prepare` and `bind_param` needs to be placed before $i auto-increments. The `execute` needs to be placed after $i auto-increments. Here's the code that works:

```
$i = 0;
//using $user_count-1 because $i needs to start at 0 to represent the indexes and it also prevents the statement from being looped an extra time.
while($i <= $user_count-1) {
if($result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM wp_users")) {
    if($count = $result->num_rows) {
        //echo $count . ' users found.';

        while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $user_password[] = $row->user_pass;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `wp_plugin_development`.`wp_users` SET `user_pass` = ? WHERE `user_login` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $user_password[$i], $user_login[$i]);
        }
    }  
$i++; 
if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$conn->error, E_USER_WARNING);}
}
```

Thank you everyone for your input!